# is for() loop maintained inside stack or for is just a statement?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Very basic code:

**Code#1**

```cpp
int i;
int counterONE = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  counterONE += 1;
}
cout << counterONE;
```

**Code#2**

```cpp
int i, j;
int CounterONE = 0, counterTWO = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    counterONE++;
  }
  counterTWO++;
}
cout << counterONE;
cout << endl << counterTWO;
```

For both of the codes my questions are:

- How do those loops work?  Are the stack frames maintained?
- How is the internal memory maintained? Is there a queue?
- Why for looks like a `function(){}` body and how to resolve the function body?

And Please don't comment any answer in short I need complete elaboration please.

Comment: (1) Choose your lagnuage, seems to be C++, why the C,java,PHP tags?

Comment: Neither example has anything to do with recursion or the stack.

Comment: (2) The only "stack" here is for allocating space for the local variable (and that doesn't even have to be a stack, but is so in most implementations I am aware of)

Comment: All local variables will on the same stack frame.. Each recursive call (or method call for that matter)  will create a new stack frame which will be pushed onto the java stack (in java)

Comment: `for` is not a function. Its function body doesn't look like anything because there isn't any.

Comment: other than loops what is for(),while() and do while(); in C prog

Comment: @Ruchir: What do you mean, other than loops? They are loops, or *iteration statements*, in their formal specification. And they have nothing to do with recursion (calling a function from itself) or the stack (the storage for local variables). They just control program flow within a function.

Comment: Static variable are not stored on the stack.

Comment: ok got it but how ? for(),while() and do while(); look like a function calls in C prog, can you elaborate your comment in details?

Comment: Please look at the preview pane before posting, correcting the problems you find there. Your formatting is _all over the place_ and I find it hard to believe that you didn't notice that.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit : instead of picking up my faults can't you give the solution and don't waste time on commenting rubbish, if you don't know the answer don't even comment I haven't asked you for it,have I? be practical don't cry here go home this place is only for winners.

Answer (score 3):

`for` is a simple loop that is translated to "goto" (or similar) in the machine code in order to make some commands repeat themselves

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  some code
}
some more code
```

will be translated to something like (very simplified)

```
         R_x = 0 // R_x is some register
loop:    check if R_x >= 5 
         if so, go to "after"
         some code
         increase R_x
         go to loop
after:   some more code
```

This code does not involve any recursion, and the importance of the stack here is negligible (only one is used, and only to store the automatic variables).

Comment: i am understanding what you have simplified thank you,is any data structure maintained internally?

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is that `for` is *not* a function.  It is a keyword,
introducing a special type of statement.

Don't be fooled by the parentheses.  Parentheses in C++ are overloaded:
they may be an operator (the function call operator), or they may be
punctuation, which is part of the syntax.  When they follow the keyword
`for` (or `while` or `if` or `switch`), they are punctuation, and not
the function call operator; many people, like myself, like to
differentiate the two uses by formatting them differently, putting a
space between the keyword and the opening parentheses when they are
punctation at the statement level, but using no space between the name
of a function and the `(` operator.  (Everyone I know who does this also
treats all of the formats for casting as if they were a function,
although technically...)

EDIT:

For what it's worth: you can overload the `()` operator.  The overload will be considered in cases where the parentheses are operators (and in the context of a function style cast), but not when they are punctuation.

Comment: not completely agreed , avoid C++ just tell me about C 
for(init;condition check ;inc++){...} why and how? avoid that to how about do{ } while(only condition); or only while(only condition check){...}

Comment: @Ruchir it's your fault, you tagged the question with the c++ tag too.

Comment: sorry to say : you aren't specific to your answer either don't take it into wrong way check below does @amit has written it right or not?

Comment: @Ruchir What don't you agree with?  With the exception of the overloading bit, C++ and C are exactly identical here.  The parentheses can be either an operator or punctuation (or imply grouping in an expression, which is also punctuation, and not an operator).

Comment: @Ruchir Amit has explained more or less what the compiler will do.  But that's just the definition of `for`.  (Actually, the definition of `for` is given in terms of a `while`.  But it comes out to what amit has said.)  My point is just that there is no recursion, because there is no function call involved.

Answer (score 2):

> For both of the codes my question is how do those loops work? are stack frames are maintained?

Let's look at what the compiler generates for your loop.  I took your first snippet and built the following program with it<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int i;
  int counterONE=0;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    counterONE+=1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here's the equivalent assembly code generated by gcc (using `gcc -S`)<sup>2</sup>, annotated by me:

```
        .file   "loops.c"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:                         ;; function entry point
.LFB2:
        pushq   %rbp          ;; save current frame pointer
.LCFI0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp    ;; make stack pointer new frame pointer
.LCFI1:
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)  ;; initialize counterONE to 0
        movl    $0, -8(%rbp)  ;; initialize i to 0
        jmp     .L2           ;; jump to label L2 below
.L3:
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)  ;; add 1 to counterONE
        addl    $1, -8(%rbp)  ;; add 1 to i
.L2:
        cmpl    $4, -8(%rbp)  ;; compare i to the value 4
        jle     .L3           ;; if i is <= 4, jump to L3
        movl    $0, %eax      ;; return 0
        leave
        ret
```

The only stack frame involved is the one created for the `main` function; no additional stack frames are created within the `for` loop itself.  Even if you declared a variable local to the `for` loop, such as

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
  ...
}
```

or

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
  int j;
  ...
}
```

a new stack frame will (most likely) *not* be created for the loop; any variables local to the loop will be created in the enclosing function's frame, although the variable will not be visible to code outside of the loop body.

> How internally memory is maintained is there a queue?

No additional data structures are necessary.  The only memory involved is the memory for `i` (which controls the execution of the loop) and `counterONE`, both of which are maintained on the stack<sup>3</sup>.  They are referred to by their *offset* from the address stored in the frame pointer (for example, if `%rbp` contained the address `0x8000`, then the memory for `i` would be stored at address `0x8000 - 8 == 0x7ff8` and the memory for `counterONE` would be stored at address `0x8000 - 4 == 0x7ffc`).

> why for looks like a function(){} body how to resolve the function body?

The language grammar tells the compiler how to interpret the code.

Here's the grammar for an *iteration statement* (taken from the [online C 2011 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)):

```
(6.8.5) iteration-statement:
    while ( expression ) statement
    do statement while ( expression ) ;
    for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
    for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

Likewise, here's the grammar for a function call:

```
(6.5.2) postfix-expression:
    ...
    postfix-expression ( argument-expression-listopt )
    ...
```

and a function definition:

```
(6.9.1) function-definition:
     declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-listopt compound-statement
```

During parsing, the compiler breaks the source code up into *tokens* - keywords, identifiers, constants, string literals, and punctuators.  The compiler then tries to match sequences of tokens against the grammar.

So, assuming the source file contains

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
```

the compiler will see the `for` keyword; based on the grammar, it knows to interpret the following `( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )` as a loop control body, rather than a function call or a function definition.

That's the 50,000 foot view, anyway; parsing is a pretty involved subject, and it's only part of what a compiler does.  You might want to start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages) and follow the links.

Just know that this isn't something you're going to pick up in a weekend.

---

<sup>1.  Note - formatting really matters.  If you want us to help you, you need to make your code as readable as possible.  Sloppy formatting, inconsistent indenting, etc., makes it harder to find errors, and makes it less likely that someone will take time out to help.


2. This isn't the complete listing, but the rest isn't relevant to your question. 


3. This explanation applies to commonly used architectures like x86, but be aware there are some old and/or oddball architectures that may do things differently.</sup>

Comment: @Ruchir: besides the standard linked to above, there aren't many "official" online documents related to C programming.  My go-to reference has been Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com/), currently 5th edition, which covers up to the C99 standard.  I've heard good things about K. N. King's [C Programming: A Modern Approach](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Modern-Approach-2nd-Edition/dp/0393979504), although I have no personal experience with it.  Be aware that most books and websites on C are *crap*.